# Set value of input element from TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, dom

In our Angular app, we are using a control from Telerik like:

```
<kendo-recurrence-editor [start]="startDate" (valueChange)="onRecurrenceChange($event)">
</kendo-recurrence-editor>
```

Unfortunately [they don't expose a lot of properties/events](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/scheduler/api/RecurrenceEditorComponent/), so there's no way of using the normal model binding. That's why we only can use the `valueChange` event.

If someone changes a value of an input of this control, then the `onRecurrenceChange` function is called correctly:

```
public onRecurrenceChange(e) {
  this.recurrence = e;  
  ...     
}
```

Now, the next thing we do is do validation of the input elements inside this control.

If for example the value of an input is invalid, we reset the value of the input like:

```
public onRecurrenceChange(e) {
    ...
    var inputs = this.recurrenceEditorDiv.nativeElement.querySelectorAll("input");
    inputs[3].value = 1;
}
```

The value is reset correctly, so functionally it seems to work, but at the same time we get a javascript error: `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`.

It seems the root cause is that we set this input value by manipulating the DOM ourselves in an event handler.

I tried to do this in a `setTimeout()`, but this does not solve it.

So my question is: in which way can we manipulate the DOM from TypeScript and change a value of an input element, and keep TypeScript happy?

EDIT: I created a stackblitz, but here I don't see the exception that is thrown in Visual Studio: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x1wpld. If you go to DAILY, and type in 999 in 'after x occurences', it's reset to 1. But as said, in visual studio I get the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error.

EDIT 2: it seems to be solved by putting the full validation in a setTimeout, instead of only setting the value in a setTimeout.

Comment: Could you create [a stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/)?

Comment: You should read on angular change detection, and how components work. Basically, you don't want to manipulate DOM elements, unless it's a very specific case. I'm not familiar with Kendo library, but I'm pretty sure they expose their own ngModel or similar property for a two way binding on their component. Use it, and the change will run within NgZone, i.e. withing application lifehook management.

Comment: @StepUp I added it, see EDIT.

Comment: @TotallyNewb Unfortunately it seems they don't expose it for this one: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/scheduler/api/RecurrenceEditorComponent/

Answer (score -1):

Did you try that?

```
public onRecurrenceChange(e) {
     setTimeout(() => {
       ...
       var inputs = this.recurrenceEditorDiv.nativeElement.querySelectorAll("input");
       inputs[3].value = 1;
     },
       0
     );
}
```

It seems to work for me in some cases I used it. I don't use the `Scheduler` component though.

I guess it is something like that [respective error for Kendo Angular Datepicker](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/687).

Comment: Yes, as in the StackBlitz I do this, but the error is still there.

Comment: Great! I cannot see any error in the console though. Just that "Cannot read property 'includes' of null" if the user clicks on 'NEVER', but I guess is something you are going to fix anyway.

Comment: Yes it's a quick simulation. But indeed, the error is not displayed there. But it is in my local development environment.

Comment: `TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Element'.`